# Django filter query when two datetime columns have same date

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to filter a Django queryset when two datetime columns have the same date.

I have tried the following two codes that do not work :

```
drivers = drivers.filter(deleted_at__date=F("created_at__date"))
```

and

```
drivers = drivers.filter(deleted_at__date=F("created_at"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this solution.
This is not as nice as my first try above, but it works :

```
drivers = (
    drivers.annotate(created_at_date=TruncDate("created_at"))
    .filter(deleted_at__date=F("created_at_date"))
)
```

An even simpler solution is:

```
drivers = drivers.filter(deleted_at__date=TruncDate("created_at"))
```